# Assigning std::vector to pointer inside a method

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, stdvector, lifetime

I want to create a method, which uses `std::vector`s to build up a collection of data, then do some operations on the data and finally, I want to pass the generated information through a pointer of a given argument as seen in this small example:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int* list;
    int entry_count;
};




static MyStruct createList()
{
   vector<int> vectorList;
   MyStruct data;

   vectorList.push_back(1);
   vectorList.push_back(1);
   vectorList.push_back(1);
   vectorList.push_back(1);
   vectorList.push_back(1);

   data.list = &vectorList.front();
   data.entry_count = vectorList.size();
   return data;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   MyStruct data;
   data = createList();

   return 1;
}
```

The problem is, after the method is closed, the vector is destroyed and the pointer shows nowhere.

How will I able to handle this problem in the correct way? So how can I assign this collection to a pointer without de-allocating it?

Comment: If you examine it, you will notice that `list` in `main` still is the null pointer, not a pointer to some expired vector's data. Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the function local `vectorList`, `static` and use the [`std::vector::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) for getting the underlying array via a pointer.

```
void createList(int* list)
{
   static std::vector<int> vectorList;
   // ...
   list = vectorList.data();
}
```

---

However, that makes `vectorList` to be the only instance in all of your `createList` function call. If you need different `vectorList` for different function call I would suggest wrapping all into a class.

```
#include <vector>

class MyList /* final */
{
   std::vector<int> mVectorList;

public:
   // operations via functions

   int* data() /* const noexcept */  // ---> provide a member to acces the underlying data
   {
      return mVectorList.data();
   }
};
```

Comment: This implies that there is only once instance of `vectorList`. Isn't that a serious limitation?

Comment: @lubgr using the class approach is good but I kind of find it an overkill if you need it only for small use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need to structure your code such that the owning `std::vector` outlives the scope in which any pointer into its buffer is used. Example:

```
void createList(std::vector<int>& storage, int *first)
{
    storage.push_back(42);

    first = storage.data();
}

// in main, or any function:

std::vector<int> storage;
int *first = nullptr;

createList(storage, first);
```

Here, we have passed `storage` as a *reference* (note `&`), hence any changes to it are made to the actual object created in the calling scope.

Note that it's crucial to remember that `first` might be an invalid reference once you alter `storage`, as `std::vector` might reallocate and move its buffer when upon adding new elements.

Comment: My problem ist, that I do not need the vector anymore after the method is called. The method creates couple of vector lists, with diffferent data. Then mapes the data to each other and stores the data in a certain structure, with pointers to a collection of data. So I need the vectors to process a certain collection and mapping function. Then I want to assign all the information a structure with pointers and delete the vectors after.

Comment: Then pass the data that you need by return value. This is easier and more often than not, doesn't result in any runtime overhead due to copying.

Comment: @DomiDiDongo If you're going to store a pointer to its data, you *do* need the vector for as long as you need the data. There is no way to transfer the ownership of that data out of the vector. (And the overhead of the vector object is negligible.)

Comment: I edited the example to add the structure. Yes, that I have to keep the vector is the problem I am trying to avoid. So there is no way? So have have to bind the vectors in an instance to keep the data alive ?

Answer (score 1):

As per your use-case, if there is no need to create the vector initially, then you can follow the below approach.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int* createList()
{
    static std::vector<int> internalList;
    internalList.push_back(42);
    return internalList.data();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int *first = nullptr;
    first = createList();
    std::cout<<*first;

    return 0;
}
```

The approach is to declare a static vector and then return the pointer to the first element using the `std::vector::data()` method.
For more reference follow the [C++ Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/)